# Python sympy.Plot - OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

So i want to display the g function as a graph but whenever i run it, it returns the OverflowError in the title and i can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

```
%matplotlib inline 

import sympy as sym

def g(x):

   return 1 - (sym.factorial(365) / ((365 ** x) * sym.factorial(365 - x)))

sym.plot(f(x), (x, 0, 100), ylim=(0, 1))
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Is there a specific formula that you're trying to implement? Try writing a loop with your `x` being in range [0,100] and use print statements to see the results of the operation. I think that after a certain value of `x`, your result goes to Infinity.

Comment: I am just trying to implement the formula g(x) into a graph. I've printed the results and the fraction have infinitely long numerators and denominators. I've tried to round and use float but both are throughing up errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in order to plot the function, SymPy uses NumPy to evaluate it numerically. NumPy is limited to machine precision floats, which can be no larger than ~10^309 (365! is ~10^778).

What you need to do is rewrite the expression so that it doesn't result in such large intermediary values. SymPy still [needs some work](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13739) to be able to help with this well.

We can use the identity:

- `binomial(n, x) = factorial(n)/(factorial(x - n)*factorial(x)`

to replace `factorial(365)/factorial(365 - x)` with `binomial(365, x)*factorial(x)`:

```
1 - binomial(365, x)*factorial(x)*365**-x
```

Which gives this plot

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment unfortunately I have come into a different problem with the error is now returning "cannot create mpf from x + 1" when i use the binomial function so i tried using the identity but it just gave me same error "int too large to convert to float"

Comment: Are you importing mpmath? It sounds like you are using an mpmath function instead of a sympy function.